# How to explicitly generate screenshots using Everyplay sdk 1.6+

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, uiimage, everyplay

I want to generate screen shots of a EAGLView using Everyplay SDK but unable to do it. In [Everyplay's github page](https://github.com/everyplay/everyplay-ios-sdk), change log say we can call `[[[Everyplay sharedInstance] capture] takeThumbnail];` as many times we want but I don't find any way to obtain image from that.

Also, EveryplayCapture class provides a property "thumbnailTextureId" (I guess it refers to the opengl texture) but is always 0 or nil.

I don't want to use EAGLView's -snapshot method because the resultant image is not good enough (contains rough white border around sprites) for use.

Is there any way to obtain a screenshot image from everyplay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.

In your  class (then one you pass to Everyplay init method) implement this callback methods:

```
 - (void)everyplayThumbnailReadyAtFilePath:(NSString *)thumbnailFilePath;
```

Now if you call

```
[[[Everyplay sharedInstance] capture] takeThumbnail];
```

Everyplay will call the method above to inform you that it's ready - from there you can read it as file.

Comment: I am still not sure in which class should I implement  `- (void)everyplayThumbnailReadyAtFilePath:(NSString *)thumbnailFilePath;`  . Currently I initialize Everyplay instance in appdelegate and EveryplayCapture is initialized in EAGLViewController.  Or should I implement it the class which implements the EveryplayDelegate?

Comment: You can only take a thumbnail when you are recording. Incase you trigger the takeThumbnail when you are not recording, nothing happens.

Comment: This is not what I wanted. I wanted to take screen shot from opengles content as it happens on the screen. But as my concept about thumbnail was not correct, I accept this as answer to the question.